# Regex to split string based on length and neighboring characters at split index

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Suppose this is my sample string:

```
String s = "Just a sa'mple 'String.";
```

I want to split this string such that token length will be always less than or equal to 5 characters and also the neighboring characters at the split index are either alphanumeric or white space.

```
String tokens[] = s.split(<regex>);
```

So the tokens array here should contain following string tokens:

```
"Just ","a s","a'mpl","e 'St","ring."
```

Note that second token "a s" is expected to have only three characters. I can't split second token like "a sa'" or "a sa" will be incorrect as a non alphanumeric character "'" (single quote) will be before split index in first case and it will be after split index in the second case.

I am trying to achieve this using Java.

I have tried iterating on String and decrementing the split index if I find neighbor character of split index other than alphanumeric or white space. I feel that my current approach is making the code complicated and using regex instead will simplify the code.

Comment: I have tried iterating on String and decrementing the split index if I find neighbor character of split index other than alphanumeric or white space. I feel that my current approach is making the code complected and using regex instead will simplify the code. I'll update the question with code snippet as soon as I'll get access to my laptop.

Comment: Reason for the down-vote please. That might help me improve this question and also any future question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See whether this code helps

`(?<=[\w\d\s.]|^)[\w\d\s.].{0,3}[\w\d\s.](?=[\w\d\s.]|$)`

[regex101 online test](https://regex101.com/r/SN2qQF/1)

> neighboring characters at the split index are either alphanumeric or white space

I am assuming you want to match `.` as well instead of only alphanumerics characters on edges, since your last group has it.

In java it would be like this *(code provided by regex101)*

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(?<=[\\w\\d\\s.]|^)[\\w\\d\\s.].{0,3}[\\w\\d\\s.](?=[\\w\\d\\s.]|$)";
final String string = "Just a sa'mple 'String.";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

result:

```
Full match: Just 
Full match: a s
Full match: a'mpl
Full match: e 'St
Full match: ring.
```